# Why does Structured Streaming fail with "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class"?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I'd like to run a Spark application using Structured Streaming with PySpark.

I use Spark 2.2 with Kafka 0.10 version.

I fail with the following error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

`spark-submit` command used as below:

```
/bin/spark-submit \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 \
  --master local[*] \
  /home/umar/structured_streaming.py localhost:2181 fortesting
```

`structured_streaming.py` code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StructuredStreaming").config("spark.driver.memory", "2g").config("spark.executor.memory", "2g").getOrCreate()
raw_DF = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:2181").option("subscribe", "fortesting").load()
values = raw_DF.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
values.writeStream.trigger(ProcessingTime("5 seconds")).outputMode("append").format("console").start().awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need [`spark-sql-kafka`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) for structured streaming:

```
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0
```

Also make sure that you use the same versions of Scala (2.11 above) and Spark (2.2.0) as you use on your cluster.

Comment: Making sure that the versions are the same as your spark cluster is really key. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Answer (score -1):

Please reference [This](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html)

You're using spark-streaming-kafka-0-10 which currently not support python.